# How to convert HTML date to ZonedDateTime in SpringBoot/MVC/Web?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Im writing a code with spring boot, its a web project. Im also using thymeleaf and bootstrap.

I have a model that contains a ZonedDateTime variable called 'validade'.
In my HTML/Thymeleaf file, I have a datepicker that allows you to pick day, month and year.

However, when I clicks submit, I get a spring boot error. How can I tell spring boot to convert this Date to ZonedDateTime? I cannot change this variable to LocalDate or LocalDateTime.

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
> Validation failed for object='tool'. Error count: 1
> org.springframework.validation.BindException:
> org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
> Field error in object 'tool' on field 'validade': rejected value
> [2021-01-08]; codes
> [typeMismatch.tool.validade,typeMismatch.validade,typeMismatch.java.time.ZonedDateTime,typeMismatch];
> arguments
> [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
> codes [tool.validade,validade]; arguments []; default message
> [validade]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type
> 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.ZonedDateTime' for
> property 'validade'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
> convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
> [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat
> @javax.persistence.Column java.time.ZonedDateTime] for value
> '2021-01-08'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> Parse attempt failed for value [2021-01-08]]

---

```
<form method="POST" th:object="${tool}"  th:action="@{/tools/add}">
...
    <div lang="pt-br" class='date'>
                           
    <input th:value="${tool.validade}" th:field="${tool.validade}" lang="pt-br" id='data-validade' type='date' data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD" class="form-control" />
    
    </div>
...
</form>
```

---

```
public class Tool{
...
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @Column(nullable = true, unique = false)
    private ZonedDateTime validade;

}
```

Comment: What happens if you send "2021-01-08Z" or "08-01-2021Z" ?

Comment: I dont know how to do that

Comment: change type='string' in JSP ? or to the value to show a standard input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to implement my own converter and inform spring boot of it.
The code below solves the issue.

```
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.ZoneId;
    import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinding;
    import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, ZonedDateTime> {

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convert(String source) {
        try {
            if (source == null) {
                return null;
            }
            
            if (source.contains(":") == false) {

                LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(source, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));

                ZonedDateTime atStartOfDay = ld.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());

                return atStartOfDay;
            } else {
                return ZonedDateTime.parse(source);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is not correct, according to your logs, the value 2021-01-08 was sent. That means that the date is following the pattern "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: Still an error: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'tool' on field 'validade': rejected value [2021-01-02]; codes [typeMismatch.tool.validade,typeMismatch.validade,typeMismatch.java.time.ZonedDateTime,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [tool.validade,validade]; arguments []; default message [validade]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of ...

Comment: May I ask why you need a ZonedDateTime?? you are just sending the date with no time zone, why not to use LocalDate ?